# Problem integrating CKeditor to Open Admin Laravel Admin Panel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have **Open Admin** as my admin panel for Laravel project.
[image: ckeditor Open Admin]
For content purpose I'm trying to  integrate **ckeditor** in it . this is it's documentation link[Ckeditor](https://open-admin.org/docs/en/extension-ckeditor) . i have implemented it but it's not working this is what it is showing [image: my ckeditor]

I have implemented all the related steps which is mentioned in the documentation. This below my code for the file rest of the code is present in the documentation.

**My Setup:**

- "php": "^8.1",
- "laravel/framework": "^10.10",

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use OpenAdmin\Admin\Controllers\AdminController;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Form;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Grid;
use OpenAdmin\Admin\Show;
use \App\Models\Blog;

class BlogController extends AdminController
{
    /**
     * Title for current resource.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title = 'Blog';

    /**
     * Make a grid builder.
     *
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new Blog());

        $grid->column('id', __('Id'));
        $grid->column('title', __('Title'));
        $grid->column('post_image', __('Post image'));
        $grid->column('writer_name', __('Writer name'));
        $grid->column('writer_image', __('Writer image'));
        $grid->column('published_date', __('Published date'));
        $grid->column('description', __('Description'));
        // $grid->column('page_image', __('Page image'));
        // $grid->column('tags', __('Tags'));
        $grid->column('created_at', __('Created at'));
        $grid->column('updated_at', __('Updated at'));

        return $grid;
    }

    /**
     * Make a show builder.
     *
     * @param mixed $id
     * @return Show
     */
    protected function detail($id)
    {
        $show = new Show(Blog::findOrFail($id));

        $show->field('id', __('Id'));
        $show->field('title', __('Title'));
        $show->field('post_image', __('Post image'));
        $show->field('writer_name', __('Writer name'));
        $show->field('writer_image', __('Writer image'));
        $show->field('published_date', __('Published date'));
        $show->field('description', __('Description'));
        // $show->field('page_image', __('Page image'));
        // $show->field('tags', __('Tags'));
        $show->field('created_at', __('Created at'));
        $show->field('updated_at', __('Updated at'));

        return $show;
    }

    /**
     * Make a form builder.
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function form()
    {
        $form = new Form(new Blog());
        // $form->ckeditor('content');

        $form->text('title', __('Title'));
        $form->text('post_image', __('Post image'));
        $form->text('writer_name', __('Writer name'));
        $form->text('writer_image', __('Writer image'));
        $form->text('published_date', __('Published date'));
        // $form->text('page_image', __('Page image'));
        // $form->textarea('description', __('Description'));
        // $form->text('tags', __('Tags'));
        $form->ckeditor('description', __('Description'));

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Kindly help me how to integrate it into the admin panel(Open Admin) if not what's the process of integrating a 3rd party plugin of Laravel to integrating in an admin panel

Tried: i tried to implement a ckeditor built in open admin tool for posting content.

Expecting: I'm not getting it neither getting any error for it.

Comment: have done? `php artisan optimize:clear` because "If ckeditor is not showing up and tells you that it's not found run the lines below to clear the compiled services and packages"

Comment: Hello @francisco,  i already  did this as it was also mentioned in the documentation but not effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy cdn code from this link: https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.22.1/standard/ckeditor.js
and insert code in *public > vendor > open-admin-ext > ckeditor > ckeditor.js*
this method will work for you. (and don't forget php artisan optimize:clear after this)